# ionic lost permission afer close app(pwa)

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

Please, if anyone knows how to solve that..

I made a pwa with ionic and onesignal..evething is fine until i close the pwa...

After that onesignal lost the permission to notification and you have to give the permision again

next the code.

### INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

  <noscript>
    This application needs JavaScript to work, please enable JavaScript on your browser
  </noscript>


  <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
  <script>
    var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
    OneSignal.push(function () {
      OneSignal.init({
        appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      });
    });
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

### app.component.ts

in the method constructor

```
      this.oneSignal.startInit('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
      this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);
      this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(data => this.onPushReceived(data.payload));
      this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(data => this.onPushOpened(data.notification.payload));
      this.oneSignal.endInit();

}



  private onPushReceived(payload: OSNotificationPayload) {
    alert(payload.body);
  }

  private onPushOpened(payload: OSNotificationPayload) {
    alert(payload.body);
  }
```

if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So you need to persist the permission, did u do that?

Comment: not really...how should i do that ?  because if i use as apk. works fine

Comment: can you share how exactly you did integration with OneSignal? for PWA unlike native plugins which handle that for you have a need to persist state of notification permissions. And I don't see you are doing it, but I am unsure how you did the integration with OneSignal either to help

Comment: i´m new on ionic and onesignal..just one month....until now...


so i run this

ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin

npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal


then

ionic build --prod 

and copy the www folder to server....

Comment: I see, I would suggest to ensure you follow these steps here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/ . Please note that PWA (browser) is not really supported by the plugin. So you might have to integrate separately the web sdk of one signal. But then you have to ensure you persist tokens and permissions

Comment: understood....one last question...when you say persist tokens and permissions...how could i do that ?? thank you...

Comment: Its easy in Ionic 3+ you just use this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/.

Comment: cool.....thanks Sergey....sorry to bother you with so many questions...

i find this code 

OneSignal.getUserId(function (userId) {
        alert("OneSignal User ID:" + userId);
      });

with this i can get the id ...right ?

but how can i search with this id in onesignal ??
and how to make permission again automatic ??